# Css background gradient does not cover background when scrolling in browser

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have a gradient background. When the page is zoomed, the gradient does not work, only the background color is shown.

Sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0c8530 0%, #0c6027 200px, #0c6027 100%) no-repeat scroll 0% 0% #0c6027;
            }

            div {
                height: 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vLBb/

Looks like this, when scrolled:

[image]

Is it possible to make the gradient work as expected even when the page is scrolled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3vLBb/4/)

Just change `no-repeat` into `repeat-x` in your **CSS** `background`, so it should be like this:

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0c8530 0%, #0c6027 200px, #0c6027 100%) repeat-x scroll 0% 0% #0c6027;
}
```

Hope this will help you ..

Answer (score 2):

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
body{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #002265, #5397be 58%, #ffc48c 82%,#ff7900 98%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #002265, #5397be 58%, #ffc48c 82%,#ff7900 98%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #002265, #5397be 58%, #ffc48c 82%,#ff7900 98%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #002265, #5397be 58%, #ffc48c 82%,#ff7900 98%); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Comment: background-attachment: fixed ... helped me

Answer (score 0):

Set the HTML tag width and height to 100% in your CSS. If that doesn't fix it on its own also set 100% width and height to the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3vLBb/3/)

```
   body {
   background: #0c6027;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0c6027 0%, #0c8530 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#0c6027), color-stop(100%,#0c8530));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0c6027 0%,#0c8530 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0c6027 0%,#0c8530 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0c6027 0%,#0c8530 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0c6027 0%,#0c8530 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0c6027', endColorstr='#0c8530',GradientType=0 );
}
div {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be exactly the same?! Scroll (horizontally) to see the problem.